# Android tts flush

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Please don't advise to use tts.stop() to flush text from tts queue.

I want to ask suppose if I have

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"tag2");
tts.speak("Hi",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,params);
tts.speak("Hello",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,params);
```

And similarly there are a bunch of other sentences added to the queue.

My question is what will be the action if

```
tts.speak("Flushing",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null); is done
```

OR

```
tts.speak("Flushing",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,params); is done
```

where params is the same as the earlier one

Is the action different in both the cases, i.e do the sentences get flushed only when the params parameter or the utterance id is the same for them?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: The code which I have ,there are many things happening there. Looking at logcat it is not clear what is happening. What it seems is that the queue should clear in all cases, but I want to confirm whether my understanding is correct or not. Can't find a lot of information on tts, apart from basic examples.

Comment: You may want to create a smaller example to isolate what you want to check the behaviour of.

Comment: I know. But it would be good if someone who has experience in using TTS helps out. In that case that person can shed more light on this and give more valuable advice.

Comment: "do the sentences get flushed only when the params parameter or the utterance id is the same for them?" You can easily figure this out for yourself through experimentation, and that's far more valuable than having someone else tell you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, all your application queue will be flushed. The HashMap param is to pass extra info for the speech engine. In your case, if passing null onUtteranceCompleted would not be called. See document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#QUEUE_FLUSH